# Intercalate pandas dataframe columns when they are in pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The desired result is this:

```
id name
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    D
5    E
6    F
7    G
8    H
```

Currently I do it this way:

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'home_id':   ['1', '3', '5', '7'],
                   'home_name': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G'],
                   'away_id':   ['2', '4', '6', '8'],
                   'away_name': ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H']})

id_col = pd.concat([df['home_id'], df['away_id']])
name_col = pd.concat([df['home_name'], df['away_name']])

result = pd.DataFrame({'id': id_col, 'name': name_col})
result = result.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

print(result)
```

But this form uses the index to reclassify the columns, generating possible errors in cases where there are equal indexes.

How can I intercalate the column values always being:

Use the home of the 1st line, then the away of the 1st line, then the home of the 2nd line, then the away of the 2nd line and so on...

Comment: Can't you `reset_index` prior to sorting by index to prevent running into duplicate indices?

Comment: Hi @Sheldon I couldn't understand how that would help in the current case, sorry.

Comment: My point is that if you reset the index of your initial `df` prior to creating `id_col` and `name_col`, you should not face what you call "equal indexes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 2), columns=['ID', 'Name'])
print(out)
>>>
    ID  Name
0   1   A
1   2   B
2   3   C
3   4   D
4   5   E
5   6   F
6   7   G
7   8   H
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the python zip, you go iterate through both dataframes:

```
home = pd.DataFrame(df[['home_id', 'home_name']].values, columns=('id', 'name'))
away = pd.DataFrame(df[['away_id', 'away_name']].values, columns=('id', 'name'))

def zip_dataframes(df1, df2):
    rows = []
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        rows.append(df1.iloc[i, :])
        rows.append(df2.iloc[i, :])

    return pd.concat(rows, axis=1).T

zip_dataframes(home, away)

  id name
0  1    A
0  2    B
1  3    C
1  4    D
2  5    E
2  6    F
3  7    G
3  8    H
```

Comment: Hi @Andreas, thanks for your time: I imagined this option, but taking into account that this would always require the ids to be sequential, the option becomes very limited, because in fact I made a sequential example to facilitate the understanding of how I wanted the final result. But real ids are not always sequential! :/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long) with a little column header renaming:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'home_id':   ['1', '3', '5', '7'],
                   'home_name': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G'],
                   'away_id':   ['2', '4', '6', '8'],
                   'away_name': ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H']})

dfr = df.rename(columns=lambda x: '_'.join(x.split('_')[::-1])).reset_index()

df_out = (pd.wide_to_long(dfr, ['id', 'name'],  'index', 'No', sep='_', suffix='.*')
            .reset_index(drop=True)
            .sort_values('id'))

df_out
```

Output:

```
  id name
0  1    A
4  2    B
1  3    C
5  4    D
2  5    E
6  6    F
3  7    G
7  8    H
```